# ActionScript - Drawing BitmapData While Maintaining Center Registration of Display Object

Tags: actionscript-3, registration, center, draw, bitmapdata

maintaining the center registration point of a circle shape, or any other display object with center registration, while being converted to a bitmap object is proving to be difficult.

the following code converts a circle shape into a bitmap object and positions it in the center of the stage and subsequently removes its center registration poin.

the x and y origin of a new bitmapData object (top left) is the same as the x and y origin of the circle (center), but it's not possible to translate the x and y position of the bitmapData.draw() - its parameters only accept width, height, transparency and fill color.

```
var myCircle:Shape = new Shape();
myCircle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1.0);
myCircle.graphics.drawCircie(0, 0, 100);
myCircle.graphics.endFill();

var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.tx = myCircle.width / 2;
matrix.ty = myCircle.height / 2;

var myCircleBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myCircle.width, myCircle.height, true, 0x00FFFFFF);
myCircleBitmapData.draw(myCircle, matrix);

var result:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myCircleBitmapData, PixelSnapping.AUTO, true);
result.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - matrix.tx;
result.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - matrix.ty;

addChild(result);
```

with the help of a matrix translation, the new bitmap object will appear centered in the stage, but applying a regular or 3D rotation, etc., will clearly demonstrate that the registration point is now the top left corner instead of the center.

how can i convert a center registered display object into a bitmap while maintaining its center registration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it appears the most common approach is to simply add the bitmap as a child of a sprite container and rotate the sprite container rather than the bitmap itself.

```
var myCircle:Shape = new Shape();
myCircle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1.0);
myCircle.graphics.drawCircie(0, 0, 100);
myCircle.graphics.endFill();

var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.tx = myCircle.width / 2;
matrix.ty = myCircle.height / 2;

var myCircleBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myCircle.width, myCircle.height, true, 0x00FFFFFF);
myCircleBitmapData.draw(myCircle, matrix);

var myCircleBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myCircleBitmapData, PixelSnapping.AUTO, true);
myCircleBitmap.x -= matrix.tx;
myCircleBitmap.y -= matrix.ty;

var circleContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
circleContainer.addChild(myCircleBitmap);
```

alternatively, for those using Flash Professional IDE, there is the option to employ [fl.motion.MatrixTransformer.rotateAroundInternalPoint](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/MatrixTransformer.html#rotateAroundInternalPoint%28%29) instead of using a container sprite.

Answer (score 1):

The following tutorial looks like what you're trying to do.

http://www.8bitrocket.com/2007/10/30/Actionscript-3-Tutorial-BitmapData-rotation-with-a-matrix/

Comment: Sure, but the principle is valid. To rotate a bitmap, without using a container object (which would probably be simpler, but hey) you need to manipulate the matrix, offset it (to achieve the correct center) rotate it, move it back to where it started.  Then redraw the object with the matrix.